# Dynamic URL rewriting with PHP in root and non-root directories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing

For my program I use dynamic URL rewriting with PHP:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    #Rewrite the URI if there is no file or folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #rewrite all to index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In PHP I then break down the URL in its different parts. For example `http://myhost/foo/bar` returns `foo bar`. The problem I have is if the program is not located in the root directory of the server, for example `http://myhost/this/is/a/folder/hereistheprogram/foo/bar`, because then the script returnes `this is a folder hereistheprogram foo bar`. Now have the problem that I can't differentiate between the folders and the URL parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know what the path to the script file is. You can do that by either explicitly declaring the path prefix or by determining it automatically, for example:

```
$basePath = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

Then you can use that prefix and strip it from the request URI path:

```
if (substr($requestPath, 0, strlen($basePath)+1) === $basePath.'/') {
    $path = substr($requestPath, strlen($basePath));
} else {
    $path = $requestPath;
}
```

By the way: It would be better if you don’t pass the request URI path explicitly to your *index.php* but retrieve it from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_QUERY'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

And the corresponding mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks! Just to check if I've got it right, in your example we just use the rewrite rule to write every request to index.php without any parameters, and retrieving the parameters only with PHP?

Comment: @wowpatrick: *REQUEST\_URI* is the URI as specified in the HTTP request line. Doing it this way doesn’t adulterate the `$_GET` variable so that `$_GET` sill contains only the originally requested query parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure of the exact problem but..

Could you have constant 'foo' identifier used in the urls to identify where to break the string?

Comment: That would be an option, but I would like to use URLs like SiteUrl/ArticleName, which is not constant. Any other ideas?

Comment: Right, so you have `example.com/ArticleName/foo/bar` and you just want the `foo bar`?

Comment: Yep, for example `example.com/ArticleName/page/2`. In this case the PHP script would output a array with `1 => ArticleName 2=> page 3=> 2`. The problem I have is if the program is not located in the root of the server, for example `example.com/mywebsite/ArticleName/page2`, the PHP script now outputs `1 => mywebsite, 2 => ArticleName` and so, and so the associations don't work anymore.